# Output errado, eu coloco uma password valida e nao funciona

Tags: php, aplicação-web, validação

**retorno:**
string 'password invalida, apenas letras e são numeros aceites' (length=55)

```
class Validapass
{
    public function setValidapass($pass)
    {
        if (strlen($pass)<1)
            return 'escreva a password'; 
        else 
            if(!preg_match('/^[0-9a-z]$/i',$pass))
                return 'password invalida, apenas letras e são numeros aceites';
        else 
            return $pass;
    }
}
```

Comment: A senha que colocou é apenas uma letra ou um número? Mais que isso será inválida, pois a expressão regular está esperando apenas um caractere.

Comment: ja descobri! if(!preg_match('/^[0-9a-z]{4,20}$/i',$pass))

Comment: Se o `_` também for permitido, fica bem mais facil de fazer `/^\w{4,20}$/`